# SELECT query with greek characters

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains a VARCHAR row with latin_sweedish_ci collation. I want to select-like query with greek characters inside. My query is the following:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ekptes WHERE eponimo LIKE Ν '%$a%' ";
```

The $a variable has a UTF-8 greek character encoding. How I can solve this query?

Comment: if the latin1 contains the greek character you are looking for, the query should work as it is. What's the current output when you execute it?

Comment: If i set the lowercase greek letter α it outputs \u03B1

Comment: Apart from the fact you're dealing with a special character, the fact you have UTF8 on top of a latin1 database is basically dev's hell. You need to encode and decode things to move them from one side to the other.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and collation/encoding support is very different between the different database products. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

Your column is collated with swedish, not greek.

Make an `ALTER` over this table and/or column(s). Than greek characters will work correctly.